# A condition for $\mathcal{U}$ to be irregular

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, filters

I know that: If $f$ is a least function for $\mathcal{U}\subset\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ then: $\mathcal{U}$ is $(\mu,\kappa)$-regular iff $\{\xi<\kappa|cf(f(\xi))<\mu\}\in\mathcal{U}$. With that I want to prove that any such $\mathcal{U}$ with a least function cannot be $(\omega,\kappa)$-regular. (Here least function for $\mathcal{U}$ is an unbounded function such that $\{\xi|g(\xi)<f(\xi)\}\in\mathcal{U}$ implies boundedness for $g$.) Also I know $\kappa$ is regular and $\mathcal{U}$ is uniform.

If $\{\xi<\kappa|cf(f(\xi))<\omega\}\in\mathcal{U}$ is to say that $f$ takes 'mostly' successor values which does not seems weird to me. ObviouslyIi am missing something.

Comment: If $cf(f(\xi))<\omega$,then $f(\xi) =g(\xi)+1$ for some $g(\xi)$, right ? What can you say about $g$ defined this way, and $g(\xi) = f(\xi)$ whenever $cf(f(\xi))\geq \omega$ ?

Comment: There are two cases, $[g]<[f]$ in the succesor case. Or $[g]=[f]$. In the first case $g$ would be bounded mod $\mathcal{U}$, therefore resulting in $f$ being bounded. Is that it? Thanks Max!

Comment: I think you need to write it down more clearly, but the idea "$[g]<[f]$ implied $g$ bounded implies $f$ bounded" is the right one